# codemirror Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND file://themes.googleusercontent.com

Tags: codemirror

I try to use CodeMirror in electron.

It shows a error in dev tool of electron

`Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND file://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/sourcesanspro/v5/ODelI1aHBYDBqgeIAH2zlBM0YzuT7MdOe03otPbuUS0.woff`

[image]

How to solve this problem?

---

My codemirror is download from homepage https://codemirror.net/index.html
 and copy all files to my app.

When I open my electron app, it shows nothing. It takes some time to load CodeMirror. After loading CodeMirror, it will show this error in dev tool of electron.

CodeMirror still works, but CodeMirror's load time become too long.

I believe it try to connect some google font on cloud at first, then give up and show me the result.

Answer (score 0):

ok, just delete this line:

`<link rel=stylesheet href="doc/docs.css">`

everything becomes normal.